# Is there a way to change service start up type using wildcard

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd.exe

Can someone tell me if this can be done either in command prompt or powershell? I am able to stop and start service by wild carding the display name. But not sure if this can be done to change the start up type as well. Please advise. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternative using wmic (needs to be run at elevated prompt)

`wmic service where "name like 'xbox%'" call changestartmode startmode="Disabled"`

Answer (score 3):

This can be done using the [Set-Service](https://msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/reference/4.0/microsoft.powershell.management/Set-Service) PowerShell cmdlet:

```
Get-Service -DisplayName xbox* | Set-Service -StartupType Disabled
```

The above line will find all services with a displayname beginning with "xbox" and pipe the results to Set-Service and set the startup type to Disabled. Add `-WhatIf` to the end of the line to confirm the desired services are returned without changing the startup type.

Comment: Additionally, can i use this command to stop all services that has displayname 'X', except services with displayname 'Y'.

Comment: Yes, just pipe the results to Stop-Service instead of Set-Service.